# interested in the following

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can you please tell me if my sentence is correct:

context: I'm writing to a substitute teacher to ask if he is interested in teaching 2 classes the next term.

Are you interested in the following classes:
(then I describe the classes)

which is better: in the following or in these

Comment: It would help if you can explain why you are asking this question.  Just "checking your English" isn't very useful.  If you can explain why you doubt this expression it would help the question.

Comment: I'm asking because I'm not sure about the usage of following here. Is there a difference between in the following and in these?

Answer (score 1):

Both "in these classes" and "in the following classes" are fine.  The expression "in the following..." is a bit more explicit (the description of the classes will *follow*). You might use it if you had a bulleted list following the given sentence.  "In these classes" would work better if you had already described the classes and were referring back to them.

Comment: Thank you. The description will follow so I'll go with the following I think. However, there are only 2 classes so is the 'following' OK or is there another alternative?

Comment: Yes, it's OK...

Comment: @ostez both are fine as James said, I agree that with a bulleted list my go-to choice would be "the following".  Think about multiple-choice questions on exams - a lot of times the verbiage will be "choose one of the following" rather than "choose one of these".  It's more descriptive and formal.